# How do you group items with the same value in pairs? - SQL

Tags: sql

SQL beginner here! I am met with the question of listing any pair of items/things with the same value but i just can't wrap my head around it. Could ask anyone to clarify it for me?

The exact question:

*"List the names of any pair of boats that have the same type. For example one pair would be Anderson Iland Escape, because the boat type for both boats is Sprite 4000. The first name listed should be the major sort key and the second name should be the minor sort key"*

1st Table:

```
CREATE TABLE MARINA_SLIP
(SLIP_ID DECIMAL(4,0) PRIMARY KEY,
MARINA_NUM CHAR(4),
SLIP_NUM CHAR(4),
LENGTH DECIMAL(4,0),
RENTAL_FEE DECIMAL(8,2),
BOAT_NAME CHAR(50),
BOAT_TYPE CHAR(50),
OWNER_NUM CHAR(4) );

INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(1,'1','A1',40,3800.00,'Anderson II','Sprite 4000','AN75');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(2,'1','A2',40,3800.00,'Our Toy','Ray 4025','EL25');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(3,'1','A3',40,3600.00,'Escape','Sprite 4000','KE22');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(4,'1','B1',30,2400.00,'Gypsy','Dolphin 28','JU92');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(5,'1','B2',30,2600.00,'Anderson III','Sprite 3000','AN75');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(6,'2','1',25,1800.00,'Bravo','Dolphin 25','AD57');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(7,'2','2',25,1800.00,'Chinook','Dolphin 22','FE82');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(8,'2','3',25,2000.00,'Listy','Dolphin 25','SM72');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(9,'2','4',30,2500.00,'Mermaid','Dolphin 28','BL72');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(10,'2','5',40,4200.00,'Axxon II','Dolphin 40','NO27');
INSERT INTO MARINA_SLIP
VALUES
(11,'2','6',40,4200.00,'Karvel','Ray 4025','TR72');
```

2nd Table:

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER
(OWNER_NUM CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME CHAR(50),
FIRST_NAME CHAR(20),
ADDRESS CHAR(15),
CITY CHAR(15),
STATE CHAR(2),
ZIP CHAR(5) );

INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('AD57','Adney','Bruce and Jean','208 Citrus','Bowton','FL','31313');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('AN75','Anderson','Bill','18 Wilcox','Glander Bay','FL','31044');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('BL72','Blake','Mary','2672 Commodore','Bowton','FL','31313');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('EL25','Elend','Sandy and Bill','462 Riverside','Rivard','FL','31062');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('FE82','Feenstra','Daniel','7822 Coventry','Kaleva','FL','32521');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('JU92','Juarez','Maria','8922 Oak','Rivard','FL','31062');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('KE22','Kelly','Alyssa','5271 Waters','Bowton','FL','31313');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('NO27','Norton','Peter','2811 Lakewood','Lewiston','FL','32765');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('SM72','Smeltz','Becky and Dave','922 Garland','Glander Bay','FL','31044');
INSERT INTO OWNER
VALUES
('TR72','Trent','Ashton','922 Crest','Bay Shores','FL','30992');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining on the boat type while ensuring that it is not the same boat may assist here.

```
SELECT
   b1.BOAT_NAME,
   b2.BOAT_NAME,
   b1.BOAT_TYPE
FROM 
   MARINA_SLIP b1
INNER JOIN
   MARINA_SLIP b2 ON b1.BOAT_TYPE=b2.BOAT_TYPE AND
                     b1.SLIP_ID < b2.SLIP_ID
ORDER BY
  b1.BOAT_NAME,
  b2.BOAT_NAME;
```

| BOAT_NAME | BOAT_TYPE | BOAT_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anderson II | Sprite 4000 | Escape |
| Bravo | Dolphin 25 | Listy |
| Gypsy | Dolphin 28 | Mermaid |
| Our Toy | Ray 4025 | Karvel |

---

or if you would like the result set to include the `and`

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(b1.BOAT_NAME,' and ',b2.BOAT_NAME) as boat_pair,
   b1.BOAT_TYPE
FROM 
   MARINA_SLIP b1
INNER JOIN
   MARINA_SLIP b2 ON b1.BOAT_TYPE=b2.BOAT_TYPE AND
                     b1.SLIP_ID < b2.SLIP_ID
ORDER BY
  b1.BOAT_NAME,
  b2.BOAT_NAME;
```

| boat_pair | BOAT_TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| Anderson II and Escape | Sprite 4000 |
| Bravo and Listy | Dolphin 25 |
| Gypsy and Mermaid | Dolphin 28 |
| Our Toy and Karvel | Ray 4025 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vb28pmGYTYt6NSqRKiwiwa/1)

Let me know if this works for you.